# How to run other JS-files with barba.js with out breaking any functions

Tags: javascript, barbajs

I am using barba.js for page transitions but when I use it my other js-files break.

Here is my [Website](https://sleepy-murdock-0cb93a.netlify.com/index.html)

I created a **runScript** function which I implemented on all other JS-files but it's still not working.

what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here is the runscript function on one of the JS-files:

```html
const runScript = () => {
    const footer = document.querySelector('footer');

    barba.hooks.leave((data) => {
        footer.style.opacity = 0;
    });

    barba.hooks.afterEnter((data) => {
        footer.style.opacity = 1;
    });

}


runScript()

barba.init({
    transitions: [
        {
            name: "switch",
            leave({ current, next, trigger }) {

            },
            enter({ current, next, trigger }) {
                runScript()
                runScriptc()

                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
                })
            }
        }
    ],
    views: [],
    debug: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using BarbaJs v2. In that case you don't need to declare that footer behavior in every js file. You are not assigning `transition from-to` properties, also, you are missing some brackets and semicolon. You just need one js file (or typescript transpiled file) to get that working. Try using this:

```
const runScript = () => {
  const footer = document.querySelector('footer');

  barba.hooks.beforeLeave((data) => {
      footer.style.opacity = 0;
  });

  barba.hooks.afterEnter((data) => {
      footer.style.opacity = 1;
  });

}


runScript();

barba.init({
    transitions: [{

            name: "switch",

            from: { namespace : [ 'homepage' ] }, //set the "from" namespaces.

            to: { namespace : [ 'about', 'contact' ] }, //set the "to" namespaces.

            beforeLeave({ current, next, trigger }) { //before leaving the page.
                 //Begin your transition and return "resolve" when is completed.
                 return new Promise(resolve => {
                    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
                 })
            },
            afterEnter({ current, next, trigger }) {
                 //remove the transition (is not necessary to return a promise, at this point barba doesn't check for promises).

            }
        }],
    views: [],
    debug: true
});
```

`Barba.hooks` properties allows you to declare a behaviour every time a section `enters, or leave`.

Remember always set `barba-barba="wrapper"`, `data-barba="container"` and `data-barba-namespace="homepage" (or about or contact)` tags at the HTML pages you'll use. E.g:

```
<div class="main-wrapper" data-barba="wrapper"> 

    <!-- Content that will not change -->

    <section data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="homepage"> 

        <!-- Content that will change --> 

    </section>
 </div>
```

You can check [BarbaJs v2 documentation](https://barba.js.org/docs/v2/user/) for more information about transitions.